# Split string and know the relative position of the result

Tags: c#

Having a string such as:

```
string foo = "10::12"
```

How can I split the string but still mantaining the positions of the results?

To clarify, `foo` is dynamic, in a way that in a given time the string may just be `::12`. Using a simple split, I don't know if the resulting `12` was on the left of the separator or on the right.

Thanks!

Comment: why that position is important here?

Comment: If you split by `':'`, and don't remove empty entries, you will get 2 empty entries before the 12, in other words, you'll get these 3 parts: `<empty>:<empty>:12`, so it should be easy for you to figure out how it looked.

Comment: Just use .IndexOf to find :: then .Substring to read from the left/right & you will implicitly know?

Comment: What should be the sample output

Comment: You have to use determine the position before or after the split. There is no available method out of the box which does both.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static void Main()
    {
        ParseAndPrint("::12");
        ParseAndPrint("10::12");

    }

      private static void ParseAndPrint(string input)
        {
            string[] parts = input.Split(new[] {"::"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var left = parts[0];
            var right = parts[1];

            Console.WriteLine("L:" + left + " R:" + right);
        }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rHw07f

Answer (score 1):

If you use a regex to find all the numbers, you can use the [Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Capture_Index) property of the [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.8) class to find both the number and the index of that number.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches("10::12"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{match.Index}, {match.Value}");
}
```

Ouput:

> 0, 10
>   4, 12